# Convert a Entire Folder To PDF

Tags: pdf, conversion, html, merge

I want to turn an entire folder([**R** Tutorial](http://leg.ufpr.br/Rtutorial/contents.html)) that is a web site(written in HTML only) that I've already downloaded all the tree to my computer, but I want to turn this into a single PDF. Someone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. merge the HTML files into a single file (e.g. with [SoftSnow Merger](http://softsnow.griffin3.com/merger/merger.shtml))
2. print the HTML to PDF (e.g. with [CutePDF Writer](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/Writer.asp))

*SoftSnow Merger and Cute PDF Writer are freeware.*

nollaig shona dhuit!

Edit: alternatively, try this:

download the web tutorial with **[Netspider](http://www.brothersoft.com/netspider-10896.html)**.

then use [Multi-HTML Converter](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=OHOYK4Q8) to merge the HTML files.

*i'm sorry, buti don't really have any further info on this program or where i got it from (i think i found it in an ebook forum a while back), all i have is the little note included in the download:*

> This program works on multi-html files
>   that are a product of some net-spiders
>   that will grab page by page htmls and
>   bundle them up with the starting file
>   that states "start_here.html", but
>   will also work with unpacked .epub
>   files, merging them into a single html
>   with a stylesheet intact. One little
>   notice here, though. To be certain
>   that the stylesheet stays with the
>   html file, be sure its name is
>   stylesheet.css or edit that part
>   accordingly in the resulting html's
>   header.

however, it works fine for me, i use it to merge HTMLs extracted from EPUB containers.

**[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/)** can also be used to join HTML files.

Comment: you're most welcome. :)

Comment: I prefer DoPDF to CutePDF - but it is more a preference thing: http://www.dopdf.com/

Comment: Hummm, I got a problem, because if you see, the structure of the folder is too much complex and have many images, then the page when looks very problematic.

Comment: @Goyuix: yep, there are many alternatives, Bullzip has a nice PDF printer too, i'm just so used to CutePDF (i also have PDFCreator. more features but slower) although recently CutePDF added a browser toolbar to their installer ... a nuisance!

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution to this. Very annoying as there are hundreds of sites (and downloadable things) which will convert an individual HTML file. But if you want to convert a whole tree structure, nada. Except (apparently) for Adobe Acrobat Pro. Pay squillions: who wants to do that? Not me. And... a FOSS solution? Can that ***really*** be so difficult? It would probably take someone with the requisite knowledge an hour to create.

My solution: download and install Calibre. Learn how to convert from one format to another.

But... my experiments with converting directly from HTML directory to PDF throw up all kinds of annoyances and unwelcome PDF "artefacts".

Instead, try a 2-stage solution: first convert to Epub, then convert the Epub to PDF. I'd also recommend tweaking the font size and pages margins of the PDF to be produced (NB Calibre v 4.13):

- right-click --> Convert --> Convert individually --> Output format (top right): choose PDF
- click PDF output in the left-hand box --> Default font size 15 px, Monospace font size 15 px, Page margins: all set to 10.0 pt.

NB I forgot to mention: with this solution, forget about any notions of tables of contents, etc.

I hate reading documents on a computer (eyesight), and instead have an ancient 9.7" e-ink e-reader. Hence the need for PDFs. So I just keep a record somewhere of page numbers of salient parts of the PDF document and jump to them.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to convert any folder which contains multiple format such as Microsoft Office, Excel, Word, text, JPG, BMP etc. there is only one program which does it within 10–20 seconds: Adobe Acrobat Pro (any version from X onwards).